# Let $G$ a group show and $x\in G$ show that $x^{n+m}=x^nx^m$

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

Let $G$ a group show and $x\in G$ show that

$x^{n+m}=x^nx^m$

I take an arbitrary $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ and first I did induction on $m\geq 0$

If $m=0$ then $x^{n+0}=x^n=x^ne=x^nx^0$

If $m>0$ we assume its valid for m, $x^{n+m}=x^nx^m$

then $x^nx^{m+1}=x^n(x^mx)=(x^nx^m)x=x^{n+m}x=x^{n+m+1}$

so its valid for all $m\geq0$

now if $-m<0$
we assume $x^{n-m}=x^nx^{-m}$ then

$x^{x-m-1}=x^{n-m}x^{-1}=x^nx^{-m}x^{-1}=x^nx^{-m-1}$

is right?

Comment: Looks right for me

Comment: See also https://drive.google.com/file/d/1C_X39EHiWLkOevYcz8QT-VTTQWjKxPN3/view pag. 16, Theorem 1.13 (1)

Comment: Looks right to me too!

Comment: Yeah a subtle thing about notation and abstract groups is no matter how abstract and theoretic a group and a group operation may get,  $g^k$ *ALWAYS* means $\underbrace{g*g*....*g}_{k\text { times}}$ and that $k$ is *always* just a natural number and natural numbers always behave the same.  $g^n*g^m=\underbrace{g*g*....*g}_n*\underbrace{g*g*....*g}_m=\underbrace{g*g*.....*g}_{n+m}$ because ....  $n$ and $m$ are natural numbers and natural numbers *always* act like natural numbers.... and $m$ more than $n$ is *always* $n+ m$

Comment: I think that in the very last equality $x^{-m}x^{-1}=x^{-m-1}$ needs a separate proof. (I don't think you've proved $(x^{m})^{-1}=x^{-m}$, which I think you need.)

Comment: Formal power rules come from the (generalized) associative law and the following three definitions: for $n>0, \space x^n:=\prod_{i=1}^nx, \space x^{-n}:=\prod_{i=1}^nx^{-1}$, and $x^0:=e$.

Comment: I don’t know about you but I think $\underbrace{g \cdot \dots\cdot g}_{k \text{ times}}$ as well as $\prod_{i=1}^k g$ are highly informal and rely on the fact that the equality to be shown is intuitively true. If one wants to give a formal argument, one has to give an inductive definition like $g^{k+1}=g^k \cdot g$ and work his way up. But then this exercise becomes really tedious (last time I did it it was like three pages of several nested inductions). I doubt this is what OP is supposed to do, so sorry for being picky and gifting confusion :S

Answer (score 1):

You could make your proof more efficient by first proving that $x^ax^{-a}=e$ and then applying induction to the total, $n$, of the two powers.

**The base case $n=0$.**

This is the preparatory result noted above.

**The inductive step for positive $n$**

Let $a$ and $b$ be  integers such that $a+b=n+1$. Then
$$x^ax^b=x^a(x^{b-1}x)=(x^ax^{b-1})x=x^{n}x=x^{n+1}.$$

**The inductive step for negative $n$**

Let $a$ and $b$ be  integers such that $a+b=n-1$. Then
$$x^ax^b=x^a(x^{b+1}x^{-1})=(x^ax^{b+1})x^{-1}=x^{n}x^{-1}=x^{n-1}.$$